# Prove that $f(p)=(1-p)^2\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^j}{1-p^j}$ is unimodal on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, convex-analysis

> I am dealing with the following function:
> $$
> f(p)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j(p)=(1-p)^2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^j}{1-p^j},\quad 0\leq p\leq 1.
> $$
> I want to prove the function is unimodal with respect to $p$.

I use Mathematica to plot the function, which shows that the unimodality of $f(p)$ is probably correct (sorry for the absence of figure since I don't have enough reputation to include a picture).

So far, I have some results that may be useful to be referred to.
By differentiating $f_j(p)$ on $p$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}f_j(p)}{\mathrm{d}p} &= \frac{(1 - p) p^{j-1} (j (1 - p) - 2 p ( 1 - p^j))}{(1 - p^j)^2} \\
    &= \frac{(1 - p)^2 p^{j-1} (j - 2 p \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} p^i)}{(1 - p^j)^2} \\
    & = \frac{(1 - p)^2 p^{j-1} \sum_{i=1}^{j} (1 - 2 p^i)}{(1 - p^j)^2}, \\
\end{align*}
which leads to the following two observations.

- $f(p)$ is increasing in $p$ when $p\in[0,1/2].$
- The derivative of $f(p)$ at $p=1$ is negative.

Besides, I also try to prove the concavity of $f(p)$, which implies unimodality. The main idea is to prove that there exists some $j_0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{j_0}f_j(p)$ is concave in $p$ and for all $j> j_0$, $f_j(p)$ is concave in $p$. However, no significant progress has been obtained. Another idea to prove the unimodality is prove that the first derivative of $f(p)$ has only one zero.

Other information. Since
$$
\lim_{p\to 1}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{p^j}{1-p^j}=\frac{1}{1-p}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right),
$$
we have $f(p)\to 0$ as $p\to 1$.

Comment: Any ideas are welcome, even if you don't have a complete solution yet.

Comment: Have you a  proof of $f(1)=0?$

Comment: Yes, $f(1)\to 0$ as $p\to 1$.

Comment: but a detailed proof could give ideas...

Comment: The proof has been provided in the content of the new version.

Comment: @Weimin You may prove that $f''(p) < 0$ on $(0, c)$ and $f'(p) < 0$ on $[c, 1)$ for some $c$, using bounds for the functions.

Comment: @River Li, could you be more specific? I am a bit unclear about how to use bounds.

Comment: @Weimin You may choose $c = 4/5$. The proof is quite complicated. Wait to see simple proof.

Comment: @Weimin Since you have proved $f'(p) > 0$ on $(0, 1/2]$. You may prove that $f''(p) < 0$ on $(1/2, 4/5)$ and $f'(p) < 0$ on $[4/5, 1)$.

Comment: @River Li, You may write down your proof to shed lights on us.

Answer (score 2):

**Some thoughts**:

**Fact 1**: $f'(p) < 0$ on $[4/5, 1)$.

**Fact 2**: $f''(p) < 0$ on $(0, 4/5)$.

By Facts 1-2, $f(p)$ is unimodal on $(0, 1)$.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

We have
\begin{align*}
 f'(p) &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(1-p)^2p^j}{1-p^j}\right)'\\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{2(1-p)p^j}{1-p^j} + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj}{p(1-p^j)} + \frac{(1-p)^2p^{2j}j}{p(1-p^j)^2}\right)\\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left[\left(-\frac{(1-p)p^j}{1-p^j} + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj}{p(1-p^j)}\right) + \left( -\frac{(1-p)p^j}{1-p^j} + \frac{(1-p)^2p^{2j}j}{p(1-p^j)^2}\right)\right]\\
 &\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{(1-p)p^j}{1-p^j} + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj}{p(1-p^j)}\right)\\
 &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^2}{p(1-p^j)}p^j
 \left(j - \frac{p}{1-p}\right)
\end{align*}
where we use
$$-\frac{(1-p)p^j}{1-p^j} + \frac{(1-p)^2p^{2j}j}{p(1-p^j)^2}
= - \frac{(1-p)p^j}{(1-p^j)^2}[1 - p^j - (1-p)p^{j-1}j] \le 0.$$
(*Note*: Let $g(p) := 1 - p^j - (1-p)p^{j-1}j$.
We have $g'(p) = -\frac{(1-p)p^jj(j-1)}{p^2} \le 0$.
Also, $g(1) = 0$. Thus, $g(p) \ge 0$. )

Let $N = \lfloor \frac{p}{1-p}\rfloor + 1 \ge 5$.
We have
$j \ge \frac{p}{1-p}$ for all $j \ge N$,
and $j \le \frac{p}{1-p}$ for all $j = 1, 2, \cdots, N - 1$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 f'(p) &\le \sum_{j=1}^4 \frac{(1-p)^2}{p(1-p^j)}p^j
 \left(j - \frac{p}{1-p}\right)
 + \sum_{j=N}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^2}{p(1-p^j)}p^j
 \left(j - \frac{p}{1-p}\right)\\
 &\le \sum_{j=1}^4 \frac{(1-p)^2}{p(1-p^j)}p^j
 \left(j - \frac{p}{1-p}\right)
 + \sum_{j=N}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^2}{p(1-p^{N})}p^j
 \left(j - \frac{p}{1-p}\right)\\
 &= -{\frac {14\,{p}^{6}+6\,{p}^{5}+10\,{p}^{4}-{p}^{3}-{p}^{2}-2\,p-1}{
   \left( p+1 \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+p+1
   \right) }}
 + \frac{(1-p)Np^N}{p(1 - p^N)}\\
 &\le -\frac45
 - \frac{(1-p)}{p(1 - p^{p/(1-p)})}\cdot \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}\ln p}\\[6pt]
 &= - \frac45 + \frac{1}{\mathrm{e} v (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-v})}\\[6pt]
 &< 0
\end{align*}
where $v = -\frac{p\ln p}{1-p} \in [-4\ln\frac45, 1]$; we use $Np^N \le - \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}\ln p}$ (easy to prove), and
$-{\frac {14\,{p}^{6}+6\,{p}^{5}+10\,{p}^{4}-{p}^{3}-{p}^{2}-2\,p-1}{
  \left( p+1 \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+p+1
  \right) }} < - \frac45$, and $p^N \le p^{p/(1-p)}$ using $N \ge p/(1- p)$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

We have
\begin{align*}
 f''(p) &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(1-p)^2p^j}{1-p^j}\right)''\\[6pt]
 &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty
 \left(\frac{2p^j}{1-p^j}
 + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj^2(p^j+1)}{p^2(1-p^j)^3} - \frac{(1-p)(3p+1)jp^j}{p^2(1-p^j)^2}\right).
\end{align*}

We have
\begin{align*}
 &f''(p)\\ 
 ={}& \sum_{j=1}^6
 \left(\frac{2p^j}{1-p^j}
 + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj^2(p^j+1)}{p^2(1-p^j)^3} - \frac{(1-p)(3p+1)jp^j}{p^2(1-p^j)^2}\right)\\[6pt]
 &\quad + \sum_{j=7}^\infty
 \left(\frac{2p^j}{1-p^j}
 + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj^2(p^j+1)}{p^2(1-p^j)^3} - \frac{(1-p)(3p+1)jp^j}{p^2(1-p^j)^2}\right)\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \sum_{j=1}^6
 \left(\frac{2p^j}{1-p^j}
 + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj^2(p^j+1)}{p^2(1-p^j)^3} - \frac{(1-p)(3p+1)jp^j}{p^2(1-p^j)^2}\right)\\[6pt]
 &\quad + \sum_{j=7}^\infty
 \left[2p^j\left(1 + \frac43 p^j\right) 
 + \frac{(1-p)^2p^jj^2(p^j+1)}{p^2}
 \left(1 + \frac{148}{27}p^j\right)\right.\\[6pt]
 &\qquad \qquad \qquad \left.
 - \frac{(1-p)(3p+1)jp^j}{p^2}(1 + p^j)\right] \tag{1}\\[6pt]
 < {}&0
\end{align*}
where
we use $\frac{1}{1 - u} \le 1 + \frac43 u$ for all $u \in [0, 1/4]$, and $\frac{1}{(1-u)^3} \le 1 + \frac{148}{27}u$ for all $u \in [0, 1/4]$, and $\frac{1}{(1-u)^2} \ge (1 + u)^2 \ge 1 + u$ for all $u\in [0, 1/4]$,
and $p^j \in [0,1/4]$ for all $j \ge 7$.
(*Note*: (1) admits a closed form expression.)

We are done.

Comment: Aesthetics of violence

Comment: @Weimin Yes, it is complicated.